# HTTP call works, socket fails using Passport

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails.io.js

So I am running Sailsv0.10 and I have a fairly simple blueprint override for create in my WorkoutController.

```
create: function(req, res) {
var workout = req.params.all();
workout.user = req.user.id;
sails.log.verbose(workout)
Workout.create(workout).exec(function(err, workout) {
  // Error handling
  if (err) return res.negotiate(err);

  res.send(201);
  res.ok(workout.toJSON());
});
},
```

The models looks like this

Workout.js ->

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

/* e.g.
nickname: 'string'
*/
date : "date",
input: {
  type: 'string',
  enum: ['auto','manual']
},
tss : "float",
user: {
  model: 'user'
}
}

};
```

When I send a http POST to /workout everything works as expected however when I send it through a socket using the sails io socket client I get the following

```
verbose: Routing message over socket:  { method: 'post',
     data: { tss: 0, date: '2014-07-07T14:00:00.000Z', input: 'manual' },
     url: '/workout',
      headers: {} }
verbose: sending data ack packet
verbose: websocket writing 6:::2+[{"body":{},"headers":{},"statusCode":500}]
```

I am not sure if the status code 500 is related but there is no other bits of helpful information.

To try and locate the problem I have also tried

- disabling the override function
- removing the associations in the model
- removing enum
- testing using the same code of another model working through sockets

**Update**, so it seems the problem has to do with the policies

```
WorkoutController : {
        "*" : "isBasicPassportAuthenticated"
    },
isBasicPassportAuthenticated

// Credit:
// @theangryangel https://gist.github.com/theangryangel/5060446
// @Mantish https://gist.github.com/Mantish/6366642
// @anhnt https://gist.github.com/anhnt/8297229

var passport = require('passport');

// We use passport to determine if we're authenticated
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

  passport.authenticate(['basic','local'],  function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (!user) {
        return res.forbidden('You are not permitted to perform this action.');
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        next();
      });
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

Everything looks fine, so I am still not sure what is going on

Comment: What are the error messages on your server? If posting over websocket in my own app, it complains about the csrf problem and status code is 500. If csrf is disabled, it works.

Comment: The above message is all I get.  verbose: websocket writing 6:::2+[{"body":{},"headers":{},"statusCode":500}].  csrf was already disabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [req.user is undefined for socket requests in Sails.js + Angular.js + Passport.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24973959/req-user-is-undefined-for-socket-requests-in-sails-js-angular-js-passport-js)