# Why is `req.user` undefined for socket requests in Sails.js, Angular.js and Passport.js?

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, passport.js

I am trying to get the questions for the current user with a request like this:

```
http://localhost:1337/question/forme
```

As part of the GET request, I am able to access req.user.username and serve the JSONresponse when accessing it from the browser.

When I try to make the same Socket.get() request from my Angular client.js file, it doesn't work. I also tried to access it using browser console and it fails for socket.get() requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spent a large time figuring out all the moving parts to get passport working with sails on my [blog](http://blog.thesparktree.com/post/77311774912/creating-a-sails-application-using-passport)

I'll repost the relevant parts below, with an additional policy change I made.

I created a passport.js file to manage my passport configuration/strategy registration

```
/config/passport.js

var passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOneById(id).done(function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ email: email}).done(function(err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + email }); }
            if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

And then I used a policy to verify authentication. It makes use of the passport sessions if a socket request is made.

```
/api/policies/isAuthenticated.js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  // User is allowed, proceed to the next policy, 
  // or if this is the last policy, the controller
    // Sockets
    if(req.isSocket)
    {
        if(req.session &&
            req.session.passport &&
            req.session.passport.user)
        {
            //Use this:

            // Initialize Passport
            sails.config.passport.initialize()(req, res, function () {
                // Use the built-in sessions
                sails.config.passport.session()(req, res, function () {
                    // Make the user available throughout the frontend
                    //res.locals.user = req.user;
                    //the user should be deserialized by passport now;
                    next();
                });
            });

            //Or this if you dont care about deserializing the user:
            //req.user = req.session.passport.user;
            //return next();

        }
        else{
            res.json(401);
        }


    }
    else if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    else{
        // User is not allowed
        // (default res.forbidden() behavior can be overridden in `config/403.js`)
        return res.redirect('/account/login');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inject authentication methods into socket requests. For this just make a little hijack into `config/bootstrap.js`.

```
var passport = require('passport'),
http = require('http'),
initialize = passport.initialize(),
session = passport.session(),
methods = ['login', 'logIn', 'logout', 'logOut', 'isAuthenticated', 'isUnauthenticated'];

module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
    sails.removeAllListeners('router:request');
    sails.on('router:request', function(req, res) {
        initialize(req, res, function() {
            session(req, res, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                    return sails.config[500](500, req, res);
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
                    req[methods[i]] = http.IncomingMessage.prototype[methods[i]].bind(req);
                }
                sails.router.route(req, res);
            });
        });
    });

    cb();
};
```

After this hijack you can use `isAuthenticated()` and other methods from Passport in sockets.

And then inject user variable through policies like Scott says.

Comment: This is clever, but unbinding internal Sails events like `router:request` isn't really good practice; consider them like a private API.  If the core router implementation changes in the future, this would break.  It's probably not important to be able to log in/out via sockets, which is the only reason I can think of to use Passport for sockets anyway, but if you really wanted to the better place would be in a policy, or a "before" route in a [custom hook](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/concepts/extending-sails/Hooks/customhooks.md)(making sure to check req.isSocket).

Comment: I understand that this is bad practice, but I really need that Passport works with sockets. And I found only this solution that helps me. Your idea with custom hook great, thanks :)

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth/issues/11#issuecomment-49125634) for an example of doing it in a policy.

Comment: Seems to be a great solution, will try. Thanks :)

Comment: @sgress454 - I know it's been a while but is there any chance of finding this link again? It's broken now...

Comment: @TomerCagan if you mean about hooks, you can find this info on the main Sails site now: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks

Comment: @sgress454 - there's a link to some policy that (I think) should deal with authentication of socket connections. I don't believe it is specific about hooks (though I can't tell - the link it broken :-(). Original link was to https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth/issues/11#issuecomment-49125634

Answer (score 0):

Sails is great in that it routes socket requests in the same manner as HTTP requests, so that you can hit the same endpoint and execute the same code with either transport.  However, there are limits, and you're seeing one here.  Passport is Express middleware, and the socket request isn't being handled by Express, so the middleware isn't applied.

I'm no expert on Passport, but I imagine it still works using the session, which *is* available to your socket request, so I think you could probably handle this in one of two ways:

1. Read the username from the underlying session variable in your controller action
2. Use a policy to apply "user" to the `req` object if it's not already available (i.e. for non-http requests).