# Display passport.js authentication error message in view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, passport.js

I have a new [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/) project using [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) to authenticate users. I have the basic authentication working (meaning a user can sign up and successfully log in), but would like to display the appropriate error message in the login view if they don't enter the correct credentials. I can't figure out how to print any error messages in the view.

Here's my setup. I have `config/passport.js`, which contains the following:

```
var passport = require('passport'),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findOne({ id: id } , function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, email, password, done) {

    User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
         return done(null, false, { message: 'Please enter a valid email address.' });
      }

      if (!req.body.username) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Please enter your username.' });
      }

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, res) {
          if (!res) {
            return done(null, false, {
              message: 'Invalid Password'
            });
          }

          var returnUser = {
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            createdAt: user.createdAt,
            id: user.id
          };

          return done(null, returnUser, {
            message: 'Logged In Successfully'
          });

        });
    });
    }
    ));
```

Then I have `api/controllers/AuthController.js`, which contains the following:

```
var passport = require('passport');

  module.exports = {

   _config: {
     actions: false,
     shortcuts: false,
     rest: false
   },

   login: passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                            failureRedirect: '/login',
                            failureFlash: true
   }),

   logout: function(req, res) {
     req.logout();
     res.redirect('/login');
   }
 };
```

Again, this is working properly if the user fills in their correct credentials. I'm using Handlebars as my templating engine, and would like to display the error message in the login view like so:

```
<div class="alert">{{ message }}</div>
```

So far I've tried `{{ failureMessage }}` `{{ message }}` `{{ req.flash.failureMessage }}` `{{ req.flash.err }}` `{{ req.flash.message }}` to no avail. So all this to say, how do I display the appropriate error message in my view? And better yet, how would I highlight the errant field in my view?

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, looks like sails is using Express 3.0.  Per the Passport docs (http://passportjs.org/docs), you will need to explicitly add middleware to support flash (they recommend https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash).

Answer (score 2):

Not a passport expert here, but according to [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/0b3931330e245d8e8851328a7dc436433d6411c9/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L111) all you need to do is to re-render the login view with `req.flash('error')`:

```
res.render("login", {error: req.flash("error")});
```

And then in the handlebars template, display the error:

```
{{ error }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this might help you, Brad.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25151855/3499069

I think in your `serializeUser` call you need it to be `user[0].id`, but I've moved away from Passport recently, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you didn't include express flashes ?

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());
```

in your router add

```
req.flash(type, message);
```

and using

```
var t = req.flash(type); 
res.render(view, {flashMessage: t});
```